Is it possible to find a function that approximately describes data points in series?
With a pH sensor we measured the output voltage in dependence of temperature. By measuring over a temperature range we obtained a data series. That way we created several series by using different sample solutions (and plan to add more). We found that they are not only shifted (having a different pH), but also have different shapes.
Now we need to compensate the temperature so that for each sample we can obtain the corresponding voltage for 25°C. Instead of using a table with values, it would be nice to have functions that approximately describe the dependency. It will be used in software, so we can distinguish between cases and can, for example, assume a linear relationship for a certain temperature range, to make things easier.
Is there a way how to retrieve such a function, at least separate functions for ranges? This function would take U and T and yield a temperature-compensated U. Or is there a better way how to go about it?


You probably want to Google the words 'interpolation' and 'regression'

There are lots of options. Eg, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html

Thanks, I'll take a look
